# Counting posts by user id with JQ and bash

Tags: json, bash, count, jq

I am trying to count the posts made by userid 4

this is what i have so far

```
    curl -s 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' |  jq '.[] |select(.userId==4) | length'
```

output :

```
   4

   4

   4

   4

   4

   4

   4

   4

   4

   4
```

data can be found at the url but here is a quick sample

```
    [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
        "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
      }]
```

I know there are 10 post by the userId 4 so its picking them up i think there is a problem with the length part ?

it should just count the posts by userId and display the answer which is  10

EDIT :: If you think the question is acceptable please could you up-vote so i can gain reputation etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ curl -s 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' |
    jq '[ .[] |select(.userId==4) ] | length'
10
```

The outer `[ ]` converts the command result to an array you can apply the `length` on.

Comment: that works :)  

could you explain the your changes  please ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are printing every instance of a userId:4 on every line you can pipe that to a `wc -l` to get the counts.

```
curl -s 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' |  jq '.[] |select(.userId==4) | length' | wc -l

output: 10
```

Comment: hey i forgot about WC i guess i was concentration on why length would not work for me . thanks

Answer (score 0):

A very slightly shorter alternative:

```
 map(select(.userId==4))|length
```

A handy `def` to keep around (perhaps in ~/.jq) is:

```
 def count(s): reduce s as $i (0; .+1);
```

The filter you could then use would be:

```
 count(.[]|select(.userId==4))
```

(Which is one fewer non-blank characters :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce):

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $i(0;if $i.userId==4 then .+1 else . end)' \
  <(curl -s http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also try:

```
curl -s 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' |  jq 'group_by(.userId)|.[]|{userId: .[0].userId, count: (.|length)}|select(.userId==4)'
```

In a more generic way, you can use just:

```
curl -s 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' |  jq 'group_by(.userId)|.[]|{userId: .[0].userId, count: (.|length)}'
```

to count the posts per userId and another variant could be:

```
curl -s 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' |  jq 'group_by(.userId)|map({(.[0].userId|tostring): (.|length)})'
```

return a result with format `[{userId: count},...]`

Comment: group_by requires sorting, so the first solution is extraordinarily inefficient for the problem at hand.  Using group_by for the generic problem is also unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: And what is a better approach? because the generic problem is not solved anywhere in this thread.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum.  If you have a separate question, please post it as such. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not discussing anything, I'm asking a question related to the main topic so I think it's perfectly suitable here and there's no need to open a new post. If you want to answer my question please feel free to do it. I already offered a possible solution maybe no the best one if you consider efficiency but a feasible one if you consider the original case and we don't know what are the efficiency requirements so we can't either discard it as possible solution or judge about efficiency requirements. Thank you.